# iOS add multiplier to constraint programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

How to set multiplier to constraint programatically?

```
CGFloat multiplier;
```

How can i add this multiplier to my constraint?

Answer (score 2):

You can not change Multiplier after Constraint is created, because its readonly property, you can update Constant though ( you could try calculating the constant yourself ) , but if thats not the case and you really need to change multiplier , I`d suggest creating a new constraint with updated Multiplier and remove old one

```
NSLayoutConstraint *oldConstraint = YOUR_CURRENT_CONSTRAINT;
NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oldConstraint.firstItem
                                                                 attribute:oldConstraint.firstAttribute
                                                                 relatedBy:oldConstraint.relation
                                                                    toItem:oldConstraint.secondItem
                                                                 attribute:oldConstraint.secondAttribute
                                                                multiplier:NEW_MULTIPLIER
                                                                  constant:oldConstraint.constant];

[YOUR_VIEW_THAT_HOLDS_CONSTRAINT removeConstraint:oldConstraint];
[YOUR_VIEW_THAT_HOLDS_CONSTRAINT addConstraint:newConstraint];
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiplier is read only, apparently you can only set it when you create the constraint.
But you can set the constant value at any time, you can use that instead for most purposes.

```
constraint.constant = 50;
```

If you created the constraint in IB, you have to create an IBOutlet for it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just checked that and changed the answer. I think it's best to use the "constant" value instead, but maybe someone will find a better solution.

Comment: i know to use constant but don't know how to use multiplier :)

Comment: Ok I see :) so I can't help anymore, sorry. You can set the multiplier when you create the constraint, on code or in IB, but I think you cannot change it later.

Answer (score 0):

The `multiplier` property is read only. You have to remove the old NSLayoutConstraint and replace it with a new one to modify it.

However, since you know you want to change the multiplier, you can just change the constant by multiplying it yourself when changes are needed which is often less code.

Comment: okey i'll try to remove and then add new constraint. thanks for ans.